# git rerere doesn't work on commit --amend?

Tags: git, git-merge

I develop on a long-time feature branch recently, and there have master、stage branches. When I finish it on the feature branch. I need to merge that to the stage branch, because I want to package it for the staging environment and the stage branch contains specific contents for that. The first time I faced conflicts caused by maybe some other people merging too or just my feature branch being outdated, whatever resolve it normally, but after that when I merge some bug fixes on the feature branch to the stage branch again, the conflicts that I've fixed reappeared.

1. I am curious why the git doesn't remember what I solved? or am I missing some mechanism of git?

After googling I find git rerere is feeding my requirement. but it looks like doesn't work on commit --amend after I resolved conflicts. It seems to require a commit, however, I'd like to collect related things to the one commit and push it at the last. 2. How to do that? rerere is really helpful.

At the end, I tried to merge the master branch to the feature branch wish to eliminate The conflicts every time when I merge the feature to the stage branch. but conflicts still exist, which makes me more curious about question one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get what you're asking for, you can simply run `git rerere` yourself.  But you should not do this.

#### Longer: *why* you shouldn't do this

The rerere code (which *re*-uses *re*-corded *re*-solutions to prior merge conflicts) applies when you create merge conflicts.  You create merge conflicts by invoking Git's merge engine, typically by running `git merge`, but also by using `git cherry-pick` and `git revert`, including the cherry-picking steps involved in `git rebase`.

**Note that `git commit`, with or without `--amend`, is *not* in the above list!**  Running `git commit --amend` simply commits the current index content with its parent(s) set to the parent(s) of the `HEAD` commit.  I think you mostly understand this part already—but consider that, when you run `git merge` and have some set of conflict(s), you must commit the result *as a merge commit* first, before you use `git commit --amend` to store a new and different merge result.  That is, we start with:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--o--*
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

and run `git merge br2`, and we expect to end up with:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--o--*      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

To get this result after a conflict, you *must not* use `git commit --amend`.  You may use either `git commit` or `git merge --continue` to make `M`, and these will finish off the `rerere` action that was started by the conflicted merge.

If you *do* use `git commit --amend`, what you would get is not a merge commit `M` but rather a new commit `J'`:

```
            J'  <-- br1 (HEAD)
           /
          I--J
         /
...--o--*
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

but in fact Git says:

```
$ git commit --amend -m 'testing amend'
fatal: You are in the middle of a merge -- cannot amend.
```

(when I tested it, anyway).

If you get conflicts as a result of cherry-picking, the picture is a bit different, but the situation is similar:

```
...--o--o--I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
  \
   o--P--C--o--...   <-- br2

$ git cherry-pick <hash-of-C>
[merge conflicts occur]
```

Again, you do not want to `git commit --amend` at this point as that would create a new `J'`:

```
             J'  <-- br1 (HEAD)
            /
...--o--o--I--J
  \
   o--P--C--o--...   <-- br2
```

rather than a new `C'`:

```
...--o--o--I--J--C'  <-- br1 (HEAD)
  \
   o--P--C--o--...   <-- br2
```

The saved snapshot and commit messages for `J'` and `C'` are identical, but the parent of `J'` is (incorrectly) `I`, "losing" commit `J`.

Since there's no `MERGE_HEAD` file, it seems likely that Git will allow this commit, but you probably should not go about making it.  (I did not test this particular case while writing this answer.)